# Javascript & jQuery - Understanding "this" Context - unexpected "." period

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have a class I'm creating, and I'm having trouble understanding how to use `this` when you're two functions deep in something.

In my init function, `this` refers to the class object, but inside my jQuery `.each()` statement, `this` refers to whatever element you're iterating through. So, I save the reference to my class object in a variable called `tempThis`. But this is causing an error :

```
$.Audio = function() {}

$.Audio.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    this.notes = {};
    var tempThis = this;
    $('audio').each({
      // I'm getting an "Unexpected Token ." on this line
      // Right after tempThis
      tempThis.notes.$(this).id = $(this).id + " note";
    })
  }
}
```

The idea is that `this.notes` contains an object with `key: value` pairs such as `{ 'C': 'C note'}` where `C` is the id of the `audio` tag I grab in my `.each()` statement.

Why am I getting this unexpected period error? Is this the wrong approach?

I've also tried this:

```
tempThis.notes[$(this).id] = $(this).id + " note";
```

But I still get the error after `tempThis`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.each()` expects a function as the parameter, you are missing `function()` in the `each()` line

```
$.Audio = function () {}

$.Audio.prototype = {
    init: function () {
        this.notes = {};
        var tempThis = this;
        $('audio').each(function () {//missing function() here
            tempThis.notes[this.id] = this.id + " note";
        })
    }
}
```

Also to access the id of the audio element you need to use `this.id` or `$(this).prop('id')`, and to access a variable key property of `tempThis.notes` use bracket notation as shown above

Comment: @lonesomeday the update might solve the problem with property access

Comment: Ahh. Thanks a ton! Looks like thats what it was.